# How can I translate to Spanish a date with Angular pipe on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, internationalization, translate

I'm getting a date from SQL Server 2014 to my Ionic project. I'm showing a date and I'm using Angular pipe for the formatting, but it shows me the date in English. I need to show the date in Spanish. I'm trying use I18n, but it is not working. I'm sure that I'm implementing it in the wrong way.

HTML

```
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="i18n/angular-locale_es-mx.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/angular-locale_es-mx.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.mode('API', []).
        controller('theController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.date = new Date();
        }])
    </script>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ion-icon class="ct-icon date-icon-info" name="appname-clock"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <span class="dates-text" ng-non-bindable>Últ. actualización:</span>
        <span>{{travel.LastUpdateDate  | date: 'dd MMM, yyyy'}}</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to your file in there you are using AngularJS not Angular

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you use you are using Ionic?. I don't see you using any reference that indicates you are using Ionic.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://momentjs.com that is open source to convert date into spanish.

you can create a custom pipe for date with momentjs

Example:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // agosto 29º 2018, 8:51:39 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // miércoles
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // ago. 29º 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();
```

`moment.locale('es');` to step up spanish

Comment: First of all this is answer is not correct. He is not even using momentum. if you want to suggest a tool without showing him how to get his current code with the tool he is using(I18n)  post it in the comments. Second, momentum doesn't translate dates. What you did is click on the languages at the bottom momentum's of the page an all the do is to change the examples they have in spanish, not showing momentum being able to translate the languages

Comment: I think it is translate date using below code: moment.locale('en'); // default the locale to English
var localLocale = moment();

localLocale.locale('fr'); // set this instance to use French
localLocale.format('LLLL'); // dimanche 15 juillet 2012 11:01
moment().format('LLLL'); // Sunday, July 15 2012 11:01 AM

Comment: Please refer this link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Comment: You don't need to tell me to refer to that page. The answer is not for me. The answer is for the OP. Everything you posted on the comments add them to your answer, but once again. OP didn't ask for a tool to translate languages, he ask us to help him to get his setup with i18n working. Ex. "this is how you get i18n working {code} but there's another solution called momentum and you use is like {code}"

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - add a 'locale' tag to your pipe

```html
<span>{{travel.LastUpdateDate | date: 'dd MMM, yyyy':locale}}</span>
```

Step 2 -

In your component.ts file, import "*LOCALE_ID*" and "Inject" from angular/core, like this:

```js
import {
  Inject,
  LOCALE_ID,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string) {}
```

Step 3 - Add Angular's internationalization to your app - https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview

Step 4 - in your angular.json file, under your project, add the following code:

```js
 "projects": {
    "YourProjectName": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "es": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
```

There's actually more code that needs to be added to that file to make your internationlization work, but that's the main code you need to focus on for localization of date pipes.

You now have two options to translate your date pipe, 1) you can change your "*sourceLocale*" to "*es*" (spanish) and restart your app. Or 2) you can follow the steps in the Angular intrnationlization tutorial video (link I sent above) and add an "*message.es.xlf*" file to your app to represent your Spanish translations. You'd then update your server configurations in your angular.json file like so:

```js
"es": {
  "browserTarget": "NLTWeb:build:development,es"
},
```

And your build configeration in your angular.json file:

```js
"configurations": {
  "es": {
    "localize": ["es"]
  },
```

Finally, you can start your app using the following: "*npm run start -- --configuration es*"